# R data.table function to copy a value based on a reference column number on the same row

Tags: r, data.table, apply, dplyr

I have a data.table that looks like this:

```
| key | zone_1 | zone_2 | zone_3 |  v1  |  v2  |
|  A  |   4.3  |   6.9  |   12.0 |   2  |      |
|  B  |   3.7  |   5.2  |    9.7 |   4  |      |
```

I need a function that will copy the value of the column referenced in v1 to v2 for each row, so it will look like this:

```
| key | zone_1 | zone_2 | zone_3 |  v1  |  v2  |
|  A  |   4.3  |   6.9  |   12.0 |   2  |  4.3 |
|  B  |   3.7  |   5.2  |    9.7 |   4  |  9.7 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a two-column matrix to subset `df` where the first column specifies the row and the second specifies the column.

```
# setDF(df) if df is a data.table class object

df$v2 <- df[cbind(seq(nrow(df)), df$v1)]

df
#   key zone_1 zone_2 zone_3 v1   v2
# 1   A    4.3    6.9   12.0  2  4.3
# 2   B    3.7    5.2    9.7  4  9.7
```

Data used

```
structure(list(key = c("A", "B"), zone_1 = c(4.3, 3.7), zone_2 = c(6.9, 
5.2), zone_3 = c(12, 9.7), v1 = c(2L, 4L), v2 = c("4.3", " 9.7"
)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Perfect. Sorry for the poor question formatting. Will improve next time.